# C# asp.net Supporting multiple versions of a dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, antlr

I have the following dll hell:

- a ASP.Net project

  - references WebGrease

    - which references Antlr3.Runtime.dll 3.3.1.7705  [stored in /bin/ folder of the asp.net app]
  - references Custom project

    - which references NCalc.codeplex.com

      - which references Antlr3.Runtime.dll 3.1.3.22795 [stored in /bin/CustomProject/ folder of the asp.net app]

unsurprisingly these two version of Antlr are not working well together and I get "The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference" errors

I am unwilling to modify the WebGrease project.

I am attempting to upgrade the NCalc project to use 3.3.1.7705 however I am struggling with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364701/c-sharp-antlr-build-against-a-specifc-version-of-antlr3-runtime-dll)

Do you have any suggestions on how to get these two DLL's to work together?

**EDIT** unfortunately the NCalc code is not compatible with the newer version of antlr so I cannot used binding redirects

Thank you

Comment: You need to use binding redirects.

Comment: @SLaks links please. Note that the two version of Antlr.Runtime.dll are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing NCalc can use the later version of Antlr3.Runtime - ie there are no breaking changes you should be able to use a binding redirect to direct it to load the later version

eg in the web.config file ass something like

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="NCalc" publicKeyToken="xxxxxxxxx" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.1.3.0" newVersion="3.3.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly> 

    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

I don't think the 4th digit on the versions is used

Comment: "Providing NCalc can use the later version of Antlr3.Runtime" Unfortunately it cannot :-[

Comment: in the end I found a way to upgrade NCalc to run with a 3.1.0 dll and then used a binding to upgrade the final two versions where there were no breaking changes

Comment: @GreyCloud i have the same problem. How you fixed it? can you post a link or something, please?

Comment: @RaraituL sorry i am still using the solution in my previous comment